# Send ObservableCollection bound to Datagrid to Database when property is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` as its `ItemsSource`. Then each column is bound to a property of Type T that is held in the model.

When the user changes a cell it changes the property in the Model gets the set called and then I want to write the entire `ObservableCollection<T>` to my database but I can't figure out how to make this change show up in the ViewModel where the `ObservableCollection` is located.

This is my class in the model. When the percentage property is changed I just want to update the Database with the updated `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` in the ViewModel. I am not using a DataTable because it is not a SQL database.

```
class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;
    private int percentage;
    public int Percentage
    {
        get
        {
            return percentage;
        }
        set
        {
            percentage = value;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(percentage);
            doSomething();
            OnPropertyChanged("Percentage");
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {

            name = value;
        }


    }
    public MyObject(string name, int percent)
    {
        Name = name;
        Percentage = percent;
    }



    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: So right now when you make a change to a cell, the source doesn't get properly updated, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. The change in the cell updates the property correctly. The collection also shows the right value but doesn't call the set because it is just a property change and not an actual addition or removal to the collection.


Since the class with the properties is in the model it has no access to the collection in the ViewModel but I need to write the whole collection to the database

Comment: Have a second ctor that you also pass a reference to the collection.